# Javascript Http.Status is Zero Under Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome

I have a problem, I am working on a ASp.Net Web Application @ 123buy.com, in Chrome for some reason, when I go to product page, and click on Add Product, it does't work correct like in other browser. I have 2 functions that need to work in Chrome, like they do in the other browser. When it make the calls it works, but the HTTP.Status is always zero, which break other functionality like when user clicks add to product it display where it was successfully, or failed, which in chrome can't get Chrome to return a status.

Calls: AddToCart.aspx?VarId

```
function submitProduct(varId) {

            xmlhttp = null;
            var status = jQuery("#loader");

            try {

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7, Firefox, Opera, etc.
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else if (window.ActiveXObject) {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
                }
                else {

                    if (status) {
                        status.attr('class', 'div_error_container_big').attr('innerHTML',
                                    'Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.').slideDown('fast').delay(2000).slideUp('fast');
                    }
                }

                if (xmlhttp != null) {

                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = state_Change;

                    var params = "varId=" + varId;

                    if (status) {
                        status.attr("innerHTML", "<img style='padding-top:5px;' src='images/ajax-loader-2.gif' />").show();
                    }

                    var url = "addtocart.aspx?" + params;

                    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
                    xmlhttp.send(null);

                }
            }
            catch (ex) {
                alert(ex.toString());
            }
        }

function state_Change() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {

                var status = jQuery("#loader");

                if (xmlhttp.status == 200 || xmlhttp.statusText == "OK") {

                    if (status) {
                        status.attr("innerHTML", "");
                        status.hide();
                    }

                    var response = xmlhttp.responseText;

                    if (response != "") {

                        var arr = response.split('|');

                        if (arr && arr.length == 3) {
                            if (status) {
                                status.attr("innerHTML", "<div class='innerLoaderDiv'>Item was successfully added to your cart</div>"); //arr[1]
                                jQuery('#ctl00_lblCartItems').attr("innerHTML", "&nbsp;(<b>" + arr[0] + "</b>)");
                                jQuery('#ctl00_lblCartItems').tipsy({ gravity: 'n', html: true, title: function () { return arr[2]; } }); // 

                                status.fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (status) {
                            status.attr("innerHTML", "<span style='color:red;'>Sorry, an error has occured.</span>");
                            status.fadeIn(1000);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (status) {
                        status.attr("innerHTML", "");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Calls: Product.aspx?VarId

```
function GetSynchronousJSONResponse(url, postData) {

            xmlhttp = null;
            var status = jQuery("#loader");

            try {

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                    if (new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"))
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    else
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                else {

                    if (status) {
                        status.attr('class', 'div_error_container_big').attr('innerHTML',
                                    'Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.').slideDown('fast').delay(2000).slideUp('fast');
                    }
                }

                if (xmlhttp != null) {

                    // xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = state_Change;

                    if (status) {
                        status.attr("innerHTML", "<img style='padding-top:5px;' src='images/ajax-loader-2.gif' />").show();
                    }

                    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    xmlhttp.send(postData);
                    var responseText = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    return responseText;
                }
            }
            catch (ex) {
                alert(ex.toString());
            }
        }
```